# Ejbca & Hardware Security Module

Tags: certificate, hsm, ejbca

I'm using Ejbca as Certification Authority management system. The private keys and public keys store in HSM furthermore a self-signed certificate stores in hsm while storing the private key and public key

I want to know how to store the CA certificate instead of that self-signed certificate or manually import CA certificate to hsm

any advice is appreciated

I'm using Ejbca 6.0.4 and the hsm is SafeNet Protect Server

Comment: Whose Key Pair are you referring to? The users or a CA's or a Sub CA's?

Comment: CA's Key Pair I'm referring

Comment: A CA's Key Pair is always self-signed. If want to store a signed certificate with the private key, then it is a Sub CA, not a CA.

This is the hierarchy of a certificate chain:

-- CA (self-signed)
-- Sub CA (signed by CA)
-- Another Sub CA (signed by the above Sub CA)
-- Leaf certificate (signed by the above Sub CA).

Comment: but my subCA's also have self-signed certificate in hsm

Comment: A SubCA cannot be self-signed. It should be signed by the CA. Are you sure it is configured right?

Comment: A SubCA cannot be self-signed. It should be signed by the CA. Are you sure it is configured right?